# Non-modal dialog in Angular 11

Tags: angular, angular-material, modal-dialog, mat-dialog, non-modal

quick question.
I couldn't find an answer so far.
Is there any way to create a non-modal material dialog in the latest Angular version? I also looked that up here in the forum but also couldn't find a solution for older versions of Angular.

I would appreciate an answer.

Best wishes,
Nik

Comment: You can use pure html/ts/css to create whatever you need. What had you tried so far ?

Comment: I wanted to use the material dialog... I think it's not possible to use the material dialog when I want it to be non-modal right?

Comment: Yup, the material dialog pretty much is an abstraction that opens your component inside a dialog, and exposes a services that lets you communicate between the dialog and the host component. If you want to have the same feeling in terms of visuals, you can try use `mat-card` and place inside the logic that you need

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "Angular" itself is framework, and hence will never have such a feature in itself.

You've added the `angular-material` tag, so I assume that's what you're referring to - there is [MatDialog](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview) which can be further configured to be non-modal (though that depends on the definition I guess).

You can use `hasBackdrop: false` (see [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/api#MatDialogConfig)) to enable interacting with elements in the background for the `MatDialog`.

You can add a bit of `cdkDrag` magic (see [docs](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview#cdk-drag-drop-overview)) to make the dialog draggable.

I've put together a quick [example on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-173jnz).

Note that the dialog will still work as a "focus trap", i.e. if you keep pressing tab the focused elements will circle around the contents of the dialog.

If all of the above is not enough, it should be fairly easy to implement your own service for generation of fully non-modal dialogs using the Angular CDK overlay (which is the foundation upon which the `MatDialog` is actually built if I recall correctly). See the [docs](https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/overview).